# Accessing nested python Dict of coordinates in GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson

I'm making a `get` request from a REST service and returning a GeoJSON but it recognized as a dict by Python. I'm trying to access the nested list value from the `coordinates` key and the string value from the `Zone_` key. Here is a sample of the data:

```
data =  {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            }
        },
        "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                -80.1135430232235,
                                33.49892053365546
                            ],
                            [
                                -80.1165139377003,
                                33.499835530094444
                            ],
                            [
                                -80.1170369402652,
                                33.49992051898103
                            ],
                            [
                                -80.11707393820328,
                                33.49992653060032
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Zone_": "H"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                -79.62281482439842,
                                33.289964520159124
                            ],
                            [
                                -79.62376378105404,
                                33.29028749972797
                            ],
                            [
                                -79.6247927817771,
                                33.29068750016911
                            ],
                            [
                                -79.62604278223982,
                                33.29121650014533
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Zone_": "I"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem I am having is I'm stumped with trying to access the coordinates from the `geometry` key. I'm getting strings back and I don't know how to get to the nested list in `coordinates`. Here is what I have so far:

```
for x in data['features']:
    for y in x['geometry']:
        print(y)
```

Can someone please help me with this please?

Comment: `for y in x['geometry']["coordinates"]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coordinates` are nested inside the `geometry` of the `features`. So, you need to access it accordingly.

Try:

```
for feature in data['features']:
  print("Feature coods:")
  for cood in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
    print(cood)
```

This will give you the nested coordinate list:

```
Feature coods:
[[-80.1135430232235, 33.49892053365546], [-80.1165139377003, 33.499835530094444], [-80.1170369402652, 33.49992051898103], [-80.11707393820328, 33.49992653060032]]
Feature coods:
[[-79.62281482439842, 33.289964520159124], [-79.62376378105404, 33.29028749972797], [-79.6247927817771, 33.29068750016911], [-79.62604278223982, 33.29121650014533]]
```

Answer (score 0):

features is a list so you have to reference that by integer index [0]

```
for x in data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']:
    print(x)

for x in data['features'][0]['properties']:
    print(x)
```